# Global emacs-like keybindings in linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

I'm trying to emulate behaviour I get from KeyRemap4MacBook on Mac OS X. It lets me remap control-m to Enter, for instance, globally.

Is this possible with X/GNOME? Seems like xmodmap is not suitable for remapping key combinations. I tried xbindkeys to bind control-m to `xdotool key Return`, but it emits control-return. I tried `xdotool keyup control; xdotool key Return; xdotool keydown control` but it stills behaves unpredictably.

Any ideas? Kernel level hacks?

Answer (score 2):

Emacs keybindings for gtk apps

```
echo 'gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"' >>~/.gtkrc-2.0
gconftool -t string --set /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme Emacs
```

taken from here http://johan.kiviniemi.name/blag/emacs-key-bindings-in-gtk-apps/

For global keybindings check out the Emacs Wiki http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/XModMap and as an Arch Linux user I recommend checking out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap